# C# Use regex to replace member syntax of C++ constructor

Tags: c#, regex

I am a newbie with C# programmer, I try to use regex to match and replace syntax of initializer member of C++ constructor. For example:

```
TropicalFruitTOutput::TropicalFruitTOutput()
   : dad::CRunnable()
   , m_watermelon_out()
#if MAX_FRUITS == (10)
   , m_cherry_out()
#endif
{
}

NationalFruitInput::NationalFruitInput()
   , m_banana_in()
   , m_dragronFruit(PAD_GetdragronFruitPAD_B())
{
}

SpecialFruits::SpecialFruits()
   : AmazingClassType()
   , m_kiwi()
   , m_avocado(  // PRQA S 2961 # FALSEPOSITIVE QAC warning about uninitialized
                                 // Hello world
                                 // This is just a comment for
                                 // testing purpose
        m_apricotController.getApricotList())
{
}

using NewFruitsBase::NewFruitsBase;
```

Then I can use below regex to match these constructor

```
(?<=\s|^)(\w+)::\1\s*\((?:.|\n)*?\)*([^{]+)
```

Demo here: https://regex101.com/r/j1eyYk/1

but I would like to replace `()` to `{}` for each constructor's member, it should be come

```
TropicalFruitTOutput::TropicalFruitTOutput()
   : dad::CRunnable{}
   , m_watermelon_out{}
#if MAX_FRUITS == (10)
   , m_cherry_out{}
#endif
{
}

NationalFruitInput::NationalFruitInput()
   , m_banana_in{}
   , m_dragronFruit{PAD_GetdragronFruitPAD_B()}
{
}

SpecialFruits::SpecialFruits()
   : AmazingClassType{}
   , m_kiwi{}
   , m_avocado{  // PRQA S 2961 # FALSEPOSITIVE QAC warning about uninitialized
                                 // Hello world
                                 // This is just a comment for
                                 // testing purpose
        m_apricotController.getApricotList()}
{
}

using NewFruitsBase::NewFruitsBase;
```

Is there any good regex syntax to replace it?

Comment: Regex on their own are generally not sufficient to parse programming language code (and especially not C++). You can probably make one that works in some cases, but will fail in more involved ones

Comment: Some tips: 1) for code refactoring, use ReSharper, 2) never use `(?:.|\n)*?` since it is very inefficient, always use `(?s:.*?)` or `.*?` and use `RegexOptions.Singleline`, 3) if you are sure your inputs are possible to regex, you must come up with the step-by-step requirements for the pattern: it should start matching when it finds ..., grab .. or ... characters.... stop matching when it finds....

Comment: Yes there still have some exception case as my above example but I try to match as much as possible. I curently have no idea how to match and replace ( to { for each constructor member

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for your problem can be resolved with multiple regex. Where each regex would be subjective to your business need. As per your provided sample I have assumed that you want every `()` to be converted to `{}` except constructor name, comment '#' line. You also do not want to convert nested `()` into `{}`.However there might be more rules if you have multiple files to be converted. You can follow this approach and add more steps to accomplish your target.

For that I have provided the following 3 steps:

[Step 1](https://regex101.com/r/FBBXwH/1):

```
(?<!#[^\n]*)\((?![^()]*\)\))
```

This will only capture  opening bracket `(` whenever it is  not part of a comment line `#` and also whenever it is not inside part of a nested `()` brackets. Here I replace the matching `(` with `{`.

[Step 2](https://regex101.com/r/VnNyRI/1):

```
(?<!#[^\n]*)\)(?!\))
```

Here I apply this regex over the resultant of step 1. This will only capture  closing bracket `)` whenever it is  not part of a comment line `#` and also whenever it is not inside part of a nested `()` brackets. Here I replace the matching `)` with `}`.

[Step 3:](https://regex101.com/r/s8jhiR/1)
Here I apply this regex over the resultant of step 2. In the first step I also converted `()` that was part of a constructor line :: just to make the regex more simplified and to consume less operation cost. Here I find that and replace that with `{}`

```
^( |\t)*(\w+)\1*::\1*\2\{\1*}
```

Source in C#: [Run](https://ideone.com/2FXfkc)

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(?<!#[^\n]*)\((?![^()]*\)\))";
        string substitution = @"{";
        string pattern2 = @"(?<!#[^\n]*)\)(?!\))";
        string substitution2 = @"}";
        string pattern3 = @"^( |\t)*(\w+)\1*::\1*\2\{\1*}";
        string substitution3 = @"$2::$2()";        
        
        string input = @"TropicalFruitTOutput::TropicalFruitTOutput()
   : dad::CRunnable()
   , m_watermelon_out()
#if MAX_FRUITS == (10)
   , m_cherry_out()
#endif
{
}

NationalFruitInput::NationalFruitInput()
   , m_banana_in()
   , m_dragronFruit(PAD_GetdragronFruitPAD_B(xcxcxc))
{
}

SpecialFruits::SpecialFruits()
   : AmazingClassType()
   , m_kiwi()
   , m_avocado(  // PRQA S 2961 # FALSEPOSITIVE QAC warning about uninitialized
                                 // Hello world
                                 // This is just a comment for
                                 // testing purpose
        m_apricotController.getApricotList())
{
}

using NewFruitsBase::NewFruitsBase;";

        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline;
        
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, options);
        string result = regex.Replace(input, substitution);
         Regex regex2 = new Regex(pattern2, options);
        string result2=regex2.Replace(result,substitution2);
         Regex regex3 = new Regex(pattern3, options);
        string result3=regex3.Replace(result2,substitution3);        
        
        Console.WriteLine(result3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your amazing solution and very detail explanation. It's harder than I think but with your solution, I can go ahead. There still have many exception case and I need to improve and optimize base on your solution. Anyway, your answer help me a lot and very useful. I don't know how to go ahead without this solution. Thank  you so much